# dafny assertion violation when using the result of a method

Tags: dafny

I have written the program below to verify that an array is 'clean' of any particular element or not. I am having trouble asserting the result of the method. I keep getting an assertion violation when trying to assert the result of the method.

```
method Main (){
 
  
  var a:= new int[3];
  
  a[0], a[1], a[2] := 1,2,3;
  var v := isClean (a, 1);
  assert v == false;

}



method isClean (a : array <int>, key : int) returns (clean : bool)
  
  requires a.Length > 0


{
  
  var i := 0;
  
  while (i < a.Length)
  
  invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
  invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i ==> a[k] != key
  
  {
    
    if (a[i] == key) {
      
      clean := false;
      return;
    }
    
    i := i + 1;
    
  }
  
  clean := true;
  
}
```

```
Dafny 2.3.0.10506
stdin.dfy(8,11): Error: assertion violation

Dafny program verifier finished with 2 verified, 1 error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give an `ensures` clause on `isClean`. When Dafny verifies a program, it only looks at one `method` at a time. So when Dafny verifies `Main`, it does not look at the definition of `isClean` at all. Instead, it only looks at the `requires` and `ensures` clauses.

You already have the hard part of the proof done in the loop invariant. Basically you just need to modify a copy of that invariant so that it makes sense in the context of the caller, as an `ensures` clause, like this:

```
ensures clean <==> (forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] != key)
```

(Add that right below the `requires` clause on `isClean`.) In this `ensures` clause, `clean` refers to the named return value of the `isClean` method. If you add this clause, Dafny will still complain, because you are asking it to prove that a `forall` quantifier is `false`. That is equivalent to trying to prove an `exists` quantifier `true`, and requires an explicit "witness", which is a value of `k` that makes the body of the formula turn out `true`/`false`.

In this case, the intuitive reason why `isClean` returns `false` is because `a[0]` has the value 1, so `a` is *not* "clean" of 1. We can demonstrate this "witness" to Dafny by adding the assertion

```
assert a[0] == 1;
```

to the body of `Main`, right after the call to `isClean`.

---

For clarity, here is a complete version of the program that verifies:

```
method Main() {
  var a := new int[3];
  a[0], a[1], a[2] := 1,2,3;
  var v := isClean (a, 1);
  assert a[0] == 1;
  assert v == false;
}

method isClean(a: array <int>, key: int) returns (clean: bool)
  requires a.Length > 0
  ensures clean <==> (forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] != key)
{
  var i := 0;
  while (i < a.Length)
    invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
    invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i ==> a[k] != key
  {
    if (a[i] == key) {
      clean := false;
      return;
    }
    i := i + 1;
  }
  clean := true;
}
```

Comment: thanks james. you are always so helpful, this defnitely makes sense